# Recursive function doesn't return all data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I want to list only the folder names from a specific drive in Drive. So I first call the function `getFolderNames()` and add the parent folder name there. Then I call the `getChildFolders(parent)` function which gets all the sub-folders and keeps getting called recursively for every sub folder.

My problem is that the variable `folderatt` (which is supposed to hold all the information about the folder names) has only the names of the first folder, so only the sub-folders of the parent folder. But when I log inside the recursive function, it displays all the folder and sub-folder names correctly.

```
function getFolderNames() {
    var folderatt = [];

    try {

        // If you want a tree of any sub folder
        var parent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Librari").next();

        var dhenat = getChildFolders(parent);


        folderatt.push(dhenat);

    } catch (e) {

        Logger.log(e.toString());

    }
    return folderatt;

}


function getChildFolders(parent) {
    folderNames = [];

    var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
    var thirr = 1;
    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {


        var childFolder = childFolders.next();
        var allFolders = {};
        allFolders.emri = childFolder.getName();
        allFolders.id = childFolder.getId();

        folderNames.push(allFolders);
        thirr++;
        folderNames.push(thirr);
        // Logger.log(childFolder.getName());
        //    Logger.log(folderNames);


        // Recursive call for any sub-folders
        getChildFolders(childFolder);

    }
    return folderNames;

}
```

Comment: pass in folderNames as a variable else you will overwrite foldernames in every call

Comment: @Alfred https://jsfiddle.net/bvffxooo/ - Have a look at this fiddle. declare and initialize your 'folderNames' variable outside the recursive function. That should solve your problem. Also, you need not to return it to 'dhenat' var in your parent fucntion as now  'folderNames' will hold the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvffxooo/) - Have a look at this fiddle.

Declare and initialize your `'folderNames'` variable outside the recursive function. That should solve your problem. Also, you need not to return it to `'dhenat'` variable in your parent fucntion as now '`folderNames'` will hold the results

Comment: Thank you, moving the `'folderNames'` variable outside the recursive function worked.

Comment: but this makes it global, which is not such a good design approach

Comment: @Icepickle I agree with you. But that doesn't mean you should never create them either. Another solution to above problem is using closure for the child function where you will not need any global.

Comment: @Icepickle Like this - https://jsfiddle.net/6qsy0e8L/ . Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: My biggest worry is, that I don't believe that @Alfred knows why he has the current problem, and it is not really explained in your post. So he doesn't know the implications from what he did vs what you told him to do. And your second option avoids recursion, so it is not really in scope of the question. He could simply define the variable local, and use the return value as he sees fit, which would definitelly increase the re-usability of his code

Comment: @Icepickle I understand that. If that is the case, we will have to push 'folderNames' and 'childFolders' as well in the current stack as childFolders is getting reset every iteration and then handle the recursiveness. It sounds complex. I agree with you that the second option avoids the recursion but the first one servers the purpose. To make it reusable, We can pass the result array in 'getChildFolders' itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems I can see with your code, but first and for most would be that you don't really do anything with the result of the `getChildFolders( childFolder )` call, so naturally, it doesn't get included in the result set, now possibly you could change it to this

```
// Recursive call for any sub-folders
folderNames.concat( getChildFolders( childFolder ) );
```

But you should be aware, that currently your `folderNames` variable is a global variable (as it is not really defined, you just assign it a value). As long as it is global, even the concat won't help you, so you also have to assign it, eg:

```
let folderNames = [];
```

The reason that it won't help would be that each time you call the `getChildFolders` function, the folderNames would be set to an empty array again in your example, so folderNames would only contain the results of the last time you called `getChildFolders( childFolder )`. By defining it locally, there won't be such a side effect

So in the end, the first function can be rewritten as:

```
function getChildFolders(parent) {
    let folderNames = [];
    let childFolders = parent.getFolders();
    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
        let childFolder = childFolders.next();
        let allFolders = {
          emri: childFolder.getName(),
          id: childFolder.getId()
        };
        folderNames.push(allFolders);
        // Recursive call for any sub-folders
        folderNames.concat( getChildFolders( childFolder ) );
    }
    return folderNames;
}
```

Please note that I removed the thirrr variable, as it was unclear to me for what purpose you need it.

In the end this should give you a flattened array that contains your `allFolders` object. I also changed the `var` to `let` keywords as `var` is a function scoped keyword, that doesn't make sense to be defined inside a block (in this case, your while loop)

Comment: Google Apps Script gives me the same error on all the `let` variables: `Missing ; before statement`. I tried changing them back to var but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alfred Then there might be an error somewhere still, however, I think you also didn't share your full code so it's hard to say :) I didn't see btw that you have it in google-app-script, so I am guessing you are restricted to es5? Changing them to `var` should have worked